# Is there a way to apply freeze option for all the sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets containing nearly 50 sheets. I need to apply the freeze option for all the sheets.

For a single sheet I applied the freeze option by `View -> Freeze -> 1 row`.

Is there any way to apply the same freeze option for all the sheets in an easy way, instead of manually applying the freeze option in the 50 sheets?

Answer (score 1):

No, not without something like Google Apps Script (see for example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-spreadsheets-api/Cx0WZ_MAvmI)).